# Use a Worker thread together with WordPress Nonce (custom wp-api endpoint)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a plugin for WordPress which has to do a big pile of ajax requests to a custom WP API endpoint. The requests cannot be processed asynchronous, which makes it neccessary to use a Worker thread to prevent the browser from hanging during the process. So far not that complicated, but I want to use the WordPress nonce for verification. When I make a worker, I did it like this:

```
worker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

This loads the worker correctly, but now I want to talk to our custom Ajax endpoint. Therefore the script needs to be loaded through wp_enqueue_script so the nonce gets verified (am I correct here?).

```
wp_enqueue_script('itw_admin_update_products', plugins_url('assets/js/worker.js', __FILE__), [ 'jquery', 'wp-api' ], '1.0', true );
```

The above makes it off course load twice. How to load the script as a worker while still be able to verify the nonce at the Ajax endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out myself:

**Register a REST route**

```
register_rest_route('my-rest-route/v1', '/rest-action', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'callback-function',
    'permission_callback' => function () { return current_user_can('edit_pages'); },
```

**Enqueue the scripts**

The wp_localize_script() function passes along the variables we need to load the worker and to tell where the worker should do the request. wp_enqueue_script() makes sure the script is loaded at the right moment and is allowed to do requests to the API endpoint.

```
$params = array(
    'jsWorker'      => plugins_url('assets/js/the-worker.js', ITW_BASEDIR . '/ipp-to-woo.php'),
    'rest_route'    => get_rest_url(null, 'my-rest-route/v1/rest-action'),
);
wp_register_script('the_handler', plugins_url('assets/js/the-script.js', __FILE__), [ 'jquery', 'wp-api' ], '1.0', true );
wp_localize_script('the_handler', 'the_object', $params);
wp_enqueue_script('the_handler');
```

**call the worker from the-script.js**

Because we used wp_localize_script() to pass variables to the client side, we are now able to use the_object.jsWorker to load the worker. After loading the worker we pass along an object with worker.postMessage containing the API endpoint and the nonce generated by WordPress to verify ourselves.

```
worker = new Worker(the_object.jsWorker);
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var response
    response = JSON.parse(e.data)

    processResponse(response);

});

worker.postMessage({'nonce': wpApiSettings.nonce, 'url': the_object.rest_route});
```

**Do an Ajax call from the-worker.js**

And last but not least, in the-worker.js we use xhr.setRequestHeader to verify ourselves like Wordpress does.

```
function doAjaxCall(url, nonce){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', nonce );
        xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            self.postMessage(xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;
    self.doAjaxCall(data.url, data.nonce);
}, false);
```